# Why D doesn't allow object creation on stack?

Tags: class, object, heap-memory, d, stack-memory

Consider following program (See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/R8Ny0h))

```
import std.stdio;
class myclass
{
    public:
    int get_a()
    {
        return a;
    }
    private:
    int a=3;
}
int main()
{
    myclass m;  // It should be myclass m=new myclass();
    writefln("%d",m.get_a());   
    return 0;
}
```

C++ supports both automatic (stack allocated) & dynamic (heap allocated) objects. But why every class object must be dynamically allocated in D? Why D doesn't support stack allocated objects?

another surprising thing is that `ideone` gives compiler error as:

```
prog.d(14): Error: null dereference in function _Dmain
```

But when I tried it on my local machine on dmd2 compiler it gives me runtime error not compile time error. Why? Why behaviour of this program is different?
Following is the error I've got on my local machine given by dmd2.

```
object.Error@(0): Access Violation
----------------
0x00402056
0x00405F9B
0x00405EB1
0x00403D93
0x7651EE6C in BaseThreadInitThunk
0x7758377B in RtlInitializeExceptionChain
0x7758374E in RtlInitializeExceptionChain
```

Comment: "All variables are references" is rather common. Amongst the languages I'm familiar with, things like C and C++ that allow you to define types with value semantics are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: D does allow you to define types with value semantics, just as structs rather than classes. Classes are always accessed through a reference, but where you allocate the memory it references is up to you - including on the stack. The reason classes are always through reference is that's almost always the way you want to do it anyway - even in C++ - so D followed Java's lead and made it the default. But class isn't the only way to define user types so don't forget about struct!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

D does allow placing classes on the stack, see [`std.typecons.scoped`](https://dlang.org/phobos/std_typecons.html#.scoped).

The null dereference error you see on ideone happens because the compiler identified this problem during optimization (ideone seems to enable optimizations). Try adding the `-O` switch to your local compiler invocation.

Comment: then what's wrong with this program. See here: http://ideone.com/6p9isc. it fails in compilation. why compiler shows an error?

Comment: `import std.typecons;`

Comment: ok thanks. But what is the use of ! operator before constructor? & If I write myclass m=scoped !myclass(); & call the get_a() member function it results in runtime error ? Why? Thanks again

Comment: @PravasiMeet You need to use `auto`: `auto m = scoped!myclass()`. The reason is that `scoped` is a template for a struct containing the class' memory, and is implicitly convertible to the class. By doing `myclass m = scoped!myclass()`, you throw away the struct wrapper, which is immediately deallocated. `!` is the template insantiation operator (like `<>` is in C++).